# Material and Information to improve algorithmic knowledge

Tags: algorithm, bit

Lately I have been stuck on improving my algorithmic skills. And at this point I am finding myself out of good material for solving grid problems based on dfs and bsf. I somehow managed to do http://www.spoj.pl/problems/POUR1/ with a brute force logic but i recently go-ogled to find out that the problem can be done by bfs. But I can't figure out exactly how to go about it. Can someone please provide some text to read or some kind of explanation to the above mentioned problem so I can add this to my skill set. It would be extremely kind if you could even help me out for these techniques in problems like these http://www.codechef.com/problems/MMANT/ .please help as soon as possible I am really stuck in these kind of problems ant can't move on. It would also be really kind if u could provide a list of good questions about Binary Indexed Trees and segment trees and some more examples of their usage.

Thanks for the help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

One resource I've found useful is [The Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Main_Page):

> The Algorithmist is a resource dedicated to anything algorithms - from
>   the practical realm, to the theoretical realm. There are also links
>   and explanation to problemsets.

Also [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600) by Steve Skiena is extremely useful, especially the second part.

Comment: The Algorithmist is a very nice source of useful info - thanks for discovering it for me.

Comment: @Eugen Sir any help with the above mentioned problems.